# Linux says tar file doesn't exist

Tags: linux, tar, bzip2

I'm REALLY new to Linux, so just bear with me...
I downloaded a `.tar.bz2` file, and I am trying to unpack it. However, each time I attempt to unpack the tarball using `tar zxvf` Linux says "Cannot open: No such file or directory." I've tried typing the file name in a bunch of different ways and I've tried unzipping the file. I don't know if I'm using the wrong code, or what, but I've been trying to use this file for an hour, and can't seem to unpack it. Thanks for your help...

Edit: Here is a screenshot:

[image]

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrA2b.png) is one of `ls` directories

Comment: Use `--bzip2` or `-I` as well. This option tells 'tar' to read or write archives through 'bzip2'.

Comment: A screenshot of what you're doing would be helpful.

Comment: @harrymc I added a screenshot...

Comment: try adding `./` before the filename or add the entire path to the file.  Even then.. there isn't enough information.. we can't tell if you are in the same directory or what.

Comment: Add a screenshot of `ls` in the directory could tell us that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a bz2 file is not a "gzip" file - which us what your extract command expects.

Im not near my computer to double check, but im fairly sure you need the -j flag rather then -z to decompress this with tar - try

```
  tar -jxvf repy-*.tar.bz2
```